# Flex AdvancedDataGrid c/p rows issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm a newbie in Flex/AS3 development and I came across an issue that bugs me for a while now. I'm using an `AdvancedDataGrid` with some columns, and an `ArrayCollection` as the provider. I would like to make a copy/paste functionality so that multiple rows can be selected, copied, and then pasted below the selected (or last selected row).

The problem is when I copy the data from one row to another, both of those rows become highlighted on mouse-over (upper instance isn't even selectable) - just as in this topic: [Flex DataGrid/DataProvider bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259250/flex-datagrid-dataprovider-bug)

First I thought it was the issue of copying the reference, but it persist even if I use `ObjectUtil.copy()` method. Furthermore, I manually change one of the properties called "order" so that the objects of the `ArrayCollection` aren't identical, but it doesn't help. `Dataprovider` is called `newTreatmentData`, and the `DataGrid` is `newTreatmentDG`.

Any suggestions are more then welcome.

Here's part of the code that is relevant:

```
        private function getSelectedRow(event:Event):void
        {
            selectedRow = newTreatmentDG.selectedIndex;
        }
        private function copySelection(event:Event):void
        {
            bufferData = new ArrayCollection();
            var sortedIndices:Array = newTreatmentDG.selectedIndices.sort();
            for (var i:int = 0; i < newTreatmentDG.selectedIndices.length; i++){                        //copy selected rows to the buffer
                var j:int = sortedIndices[i];
                bufferData.addItem(newTreatmentData[j]);
            }
        }
        private function pasteSelection(event:Event):void
        {
            var rowsToMove:int = newTreatmentData.length - selectedRow - 1;                                 //number of rows to move after pasting

            for (var i:int = 1; i <= bufferData.length; i++){                                                   
                if (selectedRow + bufferData.length + i > newTreatmentData.length){                             // adding objects to the array collection to avoid range error
                    newTreatmentData.addItem(null);
                }
            }
                for (i = 1; i <= rowsToMove; i++){  
                newTreatmentData[selectedRow + bufferData.length + i] = ObjectUtil.copy(newTreatmentData[selectedRow + i])  //first move the rows to "give room" for pasting        
                newTreatmentData[selectedRow + bufferData.length + i].order = selectedRow + bufferData.length + i;          //manually changing the "order" property, but it doesn't help
            }
            for (var j:int = 1; j <= bufferData.length; j++){                                           //paste the data from the buffer
                newTreatmentData[selectedRow + j] = ObjectUtil.copy(bufferData[j-1])
                newTreatmentData[selectedRow + j].order = selectedRow + j;                              //again changing the order property
            }
            newTreatmentData.refresh();
        }
```

Comment: Hmm it seems that only the graphic part - row highlighting and selection is bugged, I can access and change all the rows individually.

Comment: If `newTreatmentData` is an ArrayCollection, how are yousing index based selections on it?  It shouldn't work.  ArrayCollection doesn't work with square brackets.

Comment: The index-based row switching, selection, copying and pasting is working as expected, using square brackets. Why shouldn't it work? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought, since an ArrayCollection is a wrapper of an Array, it should have the same or at least similar functionality.

Comment: That's like saying "I'm wrapping bacon around this salad, hence it has the same functionality as the salad".  They're are both an index based storage system, but they both do very different things.

Comment: I admit I don't have nearly enough knowledge about this subject for a balanced discussion, but I can tell you 2 things:1. Index selection is working (whether it should or not) and 2. with a fork you can pick a piece of salad, a piece of bacon, or a piece of salad wrapped inside some bacon ;) Thanks for your response, it got me digging deeper in the help&reference system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the `mx_internal_uid` property of every object in the `dataprovider` `ArrayCollection`. It seems that `AdvancedDataGrid` checks it to see if rows are equal. I assumed (and you know what they say about assumptions) that an object's UID changes when you copy its value into another object (hence the U in UID ;) ).